# Errors when trying to import sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project.py", line 2, in <module>
    import sklearn
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 134, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 11, in <module>
    from scipy import sparse
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'
```

I've installed the sklearn package, but whenever I try to run the script with `import sklearn` I keep getting these errors.

The terminal is telling me it is installed.

```
Requirement already satisfied: sklearn in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from sklearn)
```

Comment: Your install is broken / incomplete. scipy (a requirement) is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing another requirement which is `scipy`. You just need to run `pip3 install scipy`.

As noted by [@sascha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2320035/sascha) you may want to follow the system install instructions recommended by the [scipy project](https://www.scipy.org/install.html).

Comment: On many systems, this will install scipy for python2. It's also questionable if pip should be used when OS-packages are available.

Comment: @sascha I've updated the answer to use `pip3`. Also, I assume the usage of `pip` since it historically is the most common way of managing packages.

Comment: It's less about historical use or usual/common ways but what the scipy-devs are recommending. If binaries are shipped through pip, okay. If not, better prepare BLAS, LAPACK, GCC, GFortran and G++ before using pip.

Comment: Ah I was unaware of those specifics.

Comment: That being said, it might work [nowadays](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scipy), as many binaries have been introduced (windows with 1.0; i'm not sure about linux). What he should try probably depends on how he installed sklearn (package or pip).